# $ mysql> connect ... (from bash) what does it do?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, connection

This is not a issue, just a curiosity which I couldn't find any answer for on mysql's reference or googling:

**First of all I know that to connect to a database I would run on bash**:

`mysql -h myhost -u myusername -p`

But if I just run the `mysql` command without parameters I have the mysql> prompt and on the help I can see that there's a 'connect' command. But you can't set the user or password, just the database and host so it will always deny the access naturally.

I also tried to run mysql with just the username and password parameters from bash (to specify the db and host later) but that don't work either. So, does the connect command work **only** if you ran mysql with the username and pass which are the same for another host? Or does it have more uses?

Answer (score 1):

This is not secured but you can set mysql password on Unix shell as:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=secret

# then run mysql client to connect
mysql
mysql> connect somedb localhost
mysql> show tables
```

[See MySQL Manual for list of environment variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/environment-variables.html)

**PS:** mysql will use your unix user as mysql user for connecting. Alternatively you can set `env variable USER on Windows or NetWare`.

Comment: If I do that it will say `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` when I try to run `mysql`, then it will only work if I export and set both the username and password for the localhost, but then I wouldn't be able use `mysql> connect` to connect to a remote host if the username and password aren't the same on the other server, the main question is what's that mysql> connect used for, because I see it useless for the moment

Comment: That connect doesn't let you use a different username/password. It only lets you use database and optional host using already used `username/password` when you started mysql command.